# Spring JUnit Cannot Run TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource, while Normal Spring Env Can

Tags: spring, junit

I have a working Spring/Hibernate based web application. Now I need to use Spring JUnit 4 to write an integration test for it.
Here is my test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xxx.xml", "classpath:applicationContext.xml"})

public class TestXXX extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Test
public void testXXXExecute(){...}
}
```

With this setting of the test environment, I can access all the beans and use the sessionFactory bean to get data from database.

The problem happens with one test, with calls a production code using TransactionSynchronizationManager to implement two-phase commit.
The code looks like this:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactoryA, new SessionHolder(sessionA));
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactoryB, new SessionHolder(sessionB));
```

The code performs well in the dev and production environment, where the full Spring Framework is running. During the JUnit run, the exception is:

```
[junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@6311e359] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@56d47236] bound to thread [main]
```

I cannot use 2 lines of @TransactionConfiguration in the test class to define the two transaction managers that corresponds to the two data sources and two sessionFactory objects. I wonder if AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests cannot duplicate the transaction environment of the real Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, it is difficult to tell exactly what is wrong.  In instances where I've seen this error in the past, it was because files named in the `@ContextConfiguration` included each other.  For example, you might have file

`applicationContext-bean-cfg.xml`

that includes

`applicationContext-hibernate-cfg.xml`, but then have

`@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext-bean-cfg.xml", "classpath:/applicationContext-hibernate-cfg.xml"})`.

The other thing to check is that one of the files doesn't already have a transaction manager defined.